@Value is not injecting the property value
I have class used for sending OTP messages using email
this class requires value from the properties file called opt.length
The problem is when ever this value is called to be injected into otpLength attribute it shows as null
in the same project I have similar code but they always work except for this class
@Service
public class OTPTemplateRenderer implements EmailContentRenderer {

    @Value("${application.security.otp.length}")
    private String otpLength;


    @Override
    public String renderContent(RegisterReq user, String otp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("otpLength needed: " + otpLength);
        if (otp.length() !=  Integer.parseInt(otpLength)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid OTP");
        }

        // Read the HTML template and replace placeholders
        String htmlTemplate = Files.readString(Path.of("src/main/java/com/example/madaris/utilities/Otp_template.html"));
        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace("${name}", user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace("${message}", "Hello, this is a test email.");
        String otpPlaceholder = "${otp%d}";
        for (int i = 0; i < otp.length(); i++) {
            htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace(String.format(otpPlaceholder, i + 1), Character.toString(otp.charAt(i)));
        }

        return htmlTemplate;
}
}

Here is the output
otpLength needed: null
2024-04-21T18:07:07.321+03:00 ERROR 24544 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to render email content] with root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:623) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:777) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.madaris.utilities.OTPTemplateRenderer.renderContent(OTPTemplateRenderer.java:40) ~[classes/:na]

I have tried  to add a post constructor but didn't work

@Service
public class OTPTemplateRenderer implements EmailContentRenderer {

    @Value("${application.security.otp.length}")
    private String otpLength;

    private void validateOTPLength() {
        try {
            int length = Integer.parseInt(otpLength);
            if (length <= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("OTP length must be a positive integer.");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid OTP length configuration: " + otpLength);
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        validateOTPLength();
        // Perform any other initialization logic here
    }

    @Override
    public String renderContent(RegisterReq user, String otp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("otp: " + otp);
        System.out.println("otpLength: " + otp.length());
        System.out.println("otpLength needed: " + otpLength);
        if (otp.length() != Integer.parseInt(otpLength)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid OTP");
        }

        // Read the HTML template and replace placeholders
        String htmlTemplate = Files.readString(Path.of("src/main/java/com/example/madaris/utilities/Otp_template.html"));
        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace("${name}", user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
        htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace("${message}", "Hello, this is a test email.");
        String otpPlaceholder = "${otp%d}";
        for (int i = 0; i < otp.length(); i++) {
            htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace(String.format(otpPlaceholder, i + 1), Character.toString(otp.charAt(i)));
        }

        return htmlTemplate;
    }
}


And application.security.otp.length has a value in application.properties?

yes it has a value

An @Value like @Autowired cannot be null. If Spring at startup cannot resolve a value it will throw an exception during startup. As that isn't happening this means the instance in use isn't controlled by spring but other means, like created by yourself or some other framework outside the scope of Spring.
